# ios allow a specific number of threads on using a method at the same time

Tags: ios, multithreading, synchronized, locks

I understand that

```
 @synchronized(self) { /* lock is effective inside here only */ }
```

can keep multiple threads from accessing your method at the same time. So no one will be able to access what's inside the @synchronized{} while it is being used.

I there someway that I will allow only a limited number of threads, for example allow only 2 threads or 3 threads to access the method at the same time.

PS: I have a method which send synchronous Request, and I want to limit sending synchronous request at maximum of 3 at a time

```
   @synchronized(self) { 
  webData  = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: &response  error: &error]; 
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an `NSOperationQueue` (as Bob Kinney suggests) is a good idea.  If for some reason you don't like it, you can use a GCD semaphore.

E.g.

```
@implementation MyObject {
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore_;
}

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        semaphore_ = dispatch_semaphore_create(3);
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    dispatch_release(semaphore_);
}

- (void)doTheThing {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore_, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); {
        // Do expensive operation here.  At most 3 threads can do it at once.
    } dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore_);
}
```

[Read about “Using Dispatch Semaphores to Regulate the Use of Finite Resources” in the *Concurrency Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be better if you tried to explain your use case.  If your goal is to limit a number of running processes, I would encourage you to examine `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` as this will give you that functionality.

[Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091)

[NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html)